# how to integrate react app iis server to backend spring boot app

Tags: reactjs, windows, spring-boot, iis, deployment

Facing a issue when made a fetch call(unable to send a request to backend) to backend application(error -405 method not found) I have deployed by fontend reactjs application into IIS serevr in windows and running in port 85(i  have setted it), am running backend spring boot application in intelij IDE with localhost 8888, In fetch call added a code in reactapp with URL of springboot restful api http://localhost:8888/Browser.

I have deployed by fontend reactjs application into IIS serevr in windows and running in port 85(i  have setted it), am running backend spring boot application in intelij IDE with localhost 8888, In fetch call added a code in reactapp with URL of springboot restful api http://localhost:8888/Browser.

Please help me how i can configure to Intigrate the forentend and backend application and deploy in windows server

Am trying to install reactjs and springboot application in windows OS server

Comment: As sooner or later you might deploy both to production, try to host them as www.somedomain.com and api.somedomain.com on IIS and use `hosts` file to emulate the DNS service. All those non-standard ports only give you headaches in the long run.

Comment: Thank You so much, i was trying to host local for both, i can see running without any IDE support